implement cache in Android alongside enabling persistense true
Since frequent querying of Realtime Database data is expensive, I implemented the real-time automatic cache strategy. (Database.database().isPersistenceEnabled = true) , but I'm wondering if I should add another mechanism as I could check the local cached data before querying the remote one, in an effort to minimize the costs.
I implemented the real-time automatic cache strategy.
Database.database().isPersistenceEnabled = true

I hope to have an answer that suits me, especially from Mr @Frank van Puffelen

When you set isPersistenceEnabled to true it means that:

The Firebase Database client will cache synchronized data and keep track of all writes you've initiated while your application is running.

and

By setting this value to true, the data will be persisted to on-device (disk) storage and will thus be available again when the app is restarted (even when there is no network connectivity at that time).

When you say this:

But I'm wondering if I should add another mechanism as I could check the local cached data before querying the remote one, in an effort to minimize the costs.

There is no way you can check the cache while your device is connected to the internet. The cache is only available when your device is not connected to the internet.
If you want to specify the source of your query, perhaps you should consider using Cloud Firestore where you can call get() and specify the Source, which can be CACHE, SERVER, or DEFAULT.

Hey Miftah. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?

Thank you Mr. @Alex Mamo for your response. So if this method queries the cache only offline, we can say that it fails to minimize real-time database costs because users' devices are usually online and cannot specify the source data that we want to call. thanks anyway

always there is a way. I think I can write the json object (since realtime is a json object) in cache directory , and update it periodically .

If you have found an alternative solution, then you can go ahead with it.

ok i will do .  there 1000 of methods
